# Hash concatenation/merge without duplicate and select the max key value?

Tags: ruby

```
h1 = {"a"=> "121","b"=> "248","d"=> "192","e"=> "182"}
h2 = {"a"=> "458","b"=> "122","c"=> "562","f"=> "224","g"=> "352"}
```

This is my input I try to merge it but I had this output only

```
merge_hash = {"a"=>"121", "b"=>"248", "c"=>"562", "f"=>"224", "g"=>"352", "d"=>"192", "e"=>"182"}
```

But I want this

```
merge_hash = {"a"=>"458", "b"=>"248", "c"=>"562", "f"=>"224", "g"=>"352", "d"=>"192", "e"=>"182"}
```

I used this to merge the Hash
merge_hash = h2.merge(h1)
Anyone please help me with this Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are trying to accomplish can be done as follow:

```rb
def merge_hashes(h1:, h2:)

    keys = h1.merge(h2).keys

    hash_result = {}
    keys.each do |key|
      if h1[key].nil? && !h2[key].nil?
          hash_result[key] = h2[key]
      elsif !h1[key].nil? && h2[key].nil?
          hash_result[key] = h1[key]
      else
          hash_result[key] = h1[key] > h2[key] ? h1[key] : h2[key]
      end
    end
    hash_result
end
```

Then you can use it: `merge_hashes(h1: h1, h2: h2)`

Comment: Just a stylistic point, not sure why you would do `v1 = h1.slice(key)` and then read `v1[key]` in a bunch of places when you could just do `v1 = h1[key]` instead

Comment: yup totally agreed @max pleaner I will edit that

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you want to select the *maximum* value whenever there's an overlap. For this you can use the block form of `merge`:

```
h1.merge(h2) do |key, old_val, new_val|
  [old_val, new_val].max
end
```

This block only gets run when there's an overlap and its return value determines which value gets used

Comment: I think this only works when the bigger values are in the hash1 @max pleaner

Comment: Oh @r4cc00n I didn't fully read the question I guess. I will edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The results are ordered differently but since they are hashes, order doesn't matter, and they are equal.

Comment: `h1.merge(h2) { |_key, *values| values.max }` is a nice application for the splat operator.

Answer (score 1):

h1.merge(h2) { |_, *value| value.max }

Comment: Credited to @Stefan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678088/hash-concatination-without-duplicate-and-select-the-max-key-value#comment116125430_65678177